# Facebook for Unity SDK and desktop applications

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Can anyone confirm whether the Facebook for Unity SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity

works with desktop (standalone) Unity applications, or ONLY for iOS, Android and web? Searched the documentation but can't seem to get the answer I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work standalone. Only for IOS and Android it sends out a dummy version if you run it on PC but nothing feasible to use. When I had integrated Social Media with my PC games I used a back-end service APP42 to connect to Facebook. It wasn't the greatest it would navigate to a url page then go back to the game. But it was good enough for me to use.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Confused why this doesn't seem to be spelled out in the documentation. It seems that for Unity you have only 3 options, iOS, Android and Canvas.
Yet in this recent tutorial it seems to imply that desktop apps work as well
https://www.udemy.com/integrate-facebook-sdk-into-unity-games-assets-included/

What would possibly be the reason for facebook to shut out desktop apps?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly never thought there was a smooth way to do it on desktop. I think originally Unity's old UI would work well with Facebook canvas but Facebook's sdk code is written to not support desktop sign ins. Also I dunno if you upgraded to the new 5.4beta but it gives you errors now with the fake canvas sign in. Something with the new texture(1,1) needing to be called in Start() or Awake() method. It has more to do with Facebook just not supporting it. You basically have to either use a third party to do the work for you or write it all from scratch I elicited to use third party, then shortly went to mobile lol.